# NameError: name 'last' is not defined (though it's actually defined)

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm getting this strange error on python: I define a name (in this case, *last*), but it says that wasn't defined yet.

Code:

```
name = input("Insert name here: \n")
list = list(name)
last = list[len(list)-1]    ### here is when it's defined

print("--\n")

while not len(list) == 1:

    if last == " ":    ### here is when it's first required
        del(last)

    print(("".join(list)))
    del(last)

print(("".join(list)))
```

Error response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ocari/OneDrive/Documents/Python things/Decompor.py", line 9, in <module>
    if last == " ":
NameError: name 'last' is not defined
```

How could I solve it?

*(Btw, if I exchange the name 'last' for its desired definition (currently 'list[len(list)-1]') in each line it's required, then the code works. That proves the problem is not its definition, but somehow another kind of issue)*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `del(last)`?

Comment: For me it would delete not 'last' itself, but the result last gives, i.e., 'list[len(list)-1]'.

In which way could I delete the result, and not the name? (Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm a newbie)

Comment: To delete the last element in `list`, you can `del list[-1]`. (It’s also a good idea to pick a different name, because `list` is already a built-in name.)

Comment: two errors, deleting the list inside loop and using built-in function as variable name, try to avoid this.

Comment: @Ryan, the `del list[-1]` idea didn't work properly as `del(list[len(list)-1])` would do; Btw, thanks for the tips, guys =)

Comment: @Flowey: That’s strange. `list[-1]` and `list[len(list)-1]` should be exactly the same.

Comment: @Ryan: Forget it, it actually works as well as. I figured out that I miswrote somethings while exchanging it. Sorry for my disturbing :/ since the major error was my lack of basic informations, I ought to delete this post. Thanks for your patience, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your list is more than 1 item 
your 'last' will be del more than 1 time (because it's in the loop)
if you want delete the last item in list 
you can use pop
Try it

```
name = input("Insert name here: \n")
list = list(name)
last = list[len(list)-1]    ### here is when it's defined

print("--\n")

while not len(list) == 1:
    if list[-1] == ' ' :
      list.pop()
    if len(list) == 1 :
        break
    list.pop()
    print(("".join(list)))
```

Comment: It half solved it. The objective of that code is to delete every last letter of a string (ignoring the spaces, i.e., `" "`) until there's only one left. When I tried your version, I got some repeated strings when there was the `" "` character.

Comment: actually it is not repeat because whitespace is a character in string too
for example `a = '123'`  and  `b ='123 '` 
when you print a and b It will look equal but it is not because " " is whitespace and you can't see it

Comment: I know, that's why my original code had that `if`section; to force the skip of that character.

Comment: yes You can do the same thing like your code add if condition before pop like  `if list[-1] == ' ' : list.pop()'`  but you need add other if condition after that   like `if len(list) == 1 : break` for case like "1 2345"

Answer (score 1):

Once you `del last`, it's no longer defined. You do this at two points in your loop. Then the next time through the loop, you again try to `del last`. Since it's no longer defined, this is an error.